# Match numbers surrounded by the same text (eg., unit, currency) in a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a function that compares numbers in string where the units or currencies either side of the string match e.g.:

In: `sales increased by by 20% from "eur 20.0 m" in 2010 to "eur 24.0 m"`

Out: `20.0, 20.4`

In: `sales increased by by 20% from "eur 20.0" in 2010 to "eur 24.0"`

Out: `20.0, 20.4`

In: `sales increased by by 20% from "20.0 m" in 2010 to "24.0 m"`

Out: `20.0, 20.4`

I do not have a list of specific units I am searching for - the requirement is simply that one word either side must match.

I'm new to NLP/regex so just asking for advice on the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: Are the keywords **from** and **to** always present in your strings, and shortly followed by the targeted numbers?

Comment: @Éric the only condition is that there are two number/unit pairs in a sentence, they can be separated with any number of words.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a regular expression with backreferences (references to strings already captured with parentheses) to match units and currencies surrounding the target numbers.

This regular expression, `/([a-z]+ )([\d.]+).+?\1([\d.]+)|([\d.]+)( [a-z]+).+?([\d.]+)\5/i`, seems to do the job.

I implemented it in a JavaScript for demo and testing:

```js
function extractNumbers(str) {
    const found = str.match(/([a-z]+ )([\d.]+).+?\1([\d.]+)|([\d.]+)( [a-z]+).+?([\d.]+)\5/i);
    return found[6] === undefined ? [found[2], found[3]] : [found[4], found[6]];
}

// Demo:

console.log(extractNumbers('sales increased by by 20% from "eur 20.0 m" in 2010 to "eur 24.0 m"'));

console.log(extractNumbers('sales increased by by 20% from "eur 20.0" in 2010 to "eur 24.0"'));

console.log(extractNumbers('sales increased by by 20% from "20.0 m" in 2010 to "24.0 m"'));
```